Are the Swappable Requirements and the Type Trait std::is_swappable<> equivalent in C++17?
#include <type_traits>

struct E {
    int x;

    E(   ) = default;
    E(E&&) = delete;
    E& operator=(E&&) = delete;
};

void swap(E& a, E& b) { /* Does NOT actually swap */ }

int main(){
    static_assert( std::is_swappable_v<E> );
}

The above class E is neither MoveConstructible nor MoveAssignable. Thus, the <utility> library swap() function cannot be used (C++17:23.2.3, paragraph 3). Instead, a local custom swap() function is defined. However, it does not actually perform the swap operation.
In this context, the type trait std::is_swappable<> (C++17:23.15.4.3) yields true. Nevertheless, the Swappable requirements seem to be not fulfilled, looking at C++17:20.5.3.2, paragraph 2:

An object t is swappable with an object u if and only if:

the expressions swap(t, u) and swap(u, t) are valid when evaluated in the context described below, and
these expressions have the following effects:

the object referred to by t has the value originally held by u and
the object referred to by u has the value originally held by t.




The expressions swap(e1,e2) and swap(e2,e1) are valid for two objects of type E, but they don't have the stated effects. Is the meaning of std::is_swappable<> not exactly the same as fulfilling the Swappable requirements? Or is the compiler (and the <type_traits> library) trusting the user to implement the custom swap() function with those stated effects?

Related to this Satisfied and modeled concept?

Related to this What user-defined function signatures are expected to have a specific purpose?

writing a swap function that doesn't swap seem the be the real problem.  C++ is only going to hold your hand so much and is more likely to hurt you then help you.

Concepts go even further with that - there are concepts like std::invocable and std::regular_invocable that have strictly identical implementation, the difference is only in what you're trying to tell to the users of the interface.


Or is the compiler (and the <type_traits> library) trusting the user to implement the custom swap() function with those stated effects?

That's true for all semantic requirements on user-supplied types/functions. It is fundamentally not possible for the compiler to verify these semantics.
If you supply a library functionality with a swap implementation that isn't actually satisfying the semantics required by the library, then your program simply has undefined behavior.
All that can be checked, to varying degrees, are syntactic requirements. Type traits like std::is_swappable can only check that.
Library functionality that requires the Swappable concept might not even check the syntactic requirements though. For example, calling std::sort with an iterator value type that doesn't satisfy Swappable is also just undefined behavior, not a guaranteed compile time diagnosis, even if it doesn't satisfy std::is_swappable.

Is there a quote from the Standard explaining these semantic requirements on user-supplied functions? Or is there a quote from the Standard explicitly requiring that the swap() function actually performs a swap? (I know this sounds obvious...)

@JL There is no general requirement that swap must satisfy the semantic requirements of Swappable. It is just that standard library functions have preconditions to that effect when they are used. For example, std::sort has that precondition stated in https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#sort-2. If the precondition for a standard library function is not satisfied for a type that it is used with, then the program has undefined behavior (see https://eel.is/c++draft/library#structure.specifications-3.3).

@JL So your suggested code in the question is completely fine. However, if you try to call any standard library function that actually requires the Swappable concept to hold for the type, then your program has undefined behavior.

@JL In the case of C++20 concepts (rather than the specifiction-only concepts such as Swappable), there is a difference between a concept being satisfied, meaning the syntactic requirements hold, and the concept being modelled, meaning that the semantic requirements hold as well. There is a blanket requirement in https://eel.is/c++draft/library#res.on.requirements that makes a program IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required) if a user-supplied type does not model the required concepts or if the meaning of the program would depend on whether a satisfied concept is also modelled.

@JL These rules for C++20 concepts are stricter on the user: They permit the compiler to also check the semantic requirements to whatever degree it can and fail if a violation is detected, even if the program would have defined behavior otherwise.

Ok, so my example code is standard-compliant. But if I use that type E with a standard library function that has Swappable as a requirement(C++17)/precondition(C++20) for one of its parameters, then the program has Undefined Behavior. Thus, I conclude that the fact that std::is_swappable_v<E> yields true does not guarantee 100% that type E meets the Swappable requirements (at least not in this theoretical not-real-world corner case). Thanks! :)

@JL Yes, std::is_swappable_v<E> does not at all guarantee that Swappable is met, only that the syntactic portion is met. That's not a theoretical issue either. It is really common bug to get the semantics wrong, causing undefined behavior. Not so much for Swappable, but often for e.g. the Compare requirement.
